# Pixate not styling my views first time after launching app on iPad

Tags: ios7, pixate

I am using Pixate to style my views.
My whole application works with storyboards.
My App is an iPad only app.

I have a valid Pixate licenseKey and I am setting this up in the main:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [Pixate licenseKey:@"<my pixate license key>" forUser:@"<my email address>"];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WHVVAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

When I launch the app for the very first time on a device, the views have no styling from Pixate. When I then kill the app, and then I launch it again Pixate will start working.

When I saw this happening, I tried to call [Pixate updateStylesForAllViews]; in the [viewDidAppear:] method of my very first view of my app. But the results remain the same.

Anyone familiar with this problem? How could I troubleshoot further from here?

Comment: It appeared to be a problem with a CocoaPod from the company I work for. So the problem was not with the Pixate engine, it was with an internal CocoaPod. This CocoaPod is very specific to the company I work for, and nobody else will use it except our company. The Pixate Engine works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running on device but without Testflight, just to rule that out?

Comment: Hi, I can also see the problem in Simulator it doesn't seem to be TestFlight related. I will update the issue above.

Comment: Hi Paul, it was a problem in an internal CocoaPod that is used in our company. No problem with Pixate. I have voted to close this question.

Comment: I have the same issue - what CocoaPod was causing the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this somewhere in your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window.styleMode = PXStylingNormal;
```

Another thing to check is if you are using live CSS editing. If so, make sure you wrap that code with a condition that makes it **only run in the Simulator**. Otherwise, your on-device build will try to find your CSS file using your Mac's file path (which it won't find).

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_IPAD_SIMULATOR
  [Pixate styleSheetFromFilePath:@"../../default.css" withOrigin:PXStylesheetOriginApplication];
  Pixate.currentApplicationStylesheet.monitorChanges = YES;
#endif
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, the stylemode doesn't make a difference. I can now also see it in simulator, I realized that when I uninstall the app and then launch it from xcode it will show me the problem in simulator as well.